# Node-red Node delete callback

Tags: node-red

I wanted to delete some files whenever a node instance is deleted. Is there a callback for this like `node.on('deleted', function() {});`?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Creating Nodes](http://nodered.org/docs/creating-nodes/node-js#closing-the-node) doc:

> Whenever a new flow is deployed, the existing nodes are deleted. If
>   any of them need to tidy up state when this happens, such as
>   disconnecting from a remote system, they should register a listener on
>   the close event.
>
> ```
> this.on('close', function() {
>     // tidy up any state
> });
> ```
>
> If the node needs to do any asynchronous work to complete the tidy up,
>   the registered listener should accept an argument which is a function
>   to be called when all the work is complete.
>
> ```
> this.on('close', function(done) {
>     doSomethingWithACallback(function() {
>         done();
>     });
> });
> ```